# Automate cd into an archive directory under ~/.avfs

Tags: shell, zsh, cd-command, avfs

I use [avfs](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) to conveniently look inside archives from a shell prompt. This creates a view of the whole directory tree under `~/.avfs` (so if a file `/path/to/foo` exists then it's also visible as `~/.avfs/path/to/foo`), and additionally, if `/path/to/foo` is an archive file then `~/.avfs/path/to/foo#` is a directory which is a view of the toplevel directory of the content of the archive.

When I want to explore the inside of an archive, it's a bit cumbersome: I have to switch into the `~/.avfs` hierarchy, and the completion of `cd` [doesn't help me](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43883/completing-avfs-fake-directories-in-zsh) to type those archive names and add a `#` at the end.

I'd like to be able to run `acd foo.zip` from `/path/to/dir` and run `cd ~/.avfs/path/to/dir#`. With decent completion for `acd`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my implementation of `acd`. It does the right thing whether the argument is a directory or an archive. `acd` with no argument is equivalent to `acd .`.

```
avfs_cd () {
  case "$2" in
    "$HOME/.avfs/"*) :;;
    /*) set -- "$1" "$HOME/.avfs$2";;
    *) set -- "$1" "$HOME/.avfs$PWD/$2"
  esac
  if ! [ -d "$2" ]; then
    set -- "$1" "${2}#"
  fi
  "$1" "$2"
}
alias acd='avfs_cd cd'
alias apushd='avfs_cd pushd'
```

And here's my zsh completion function:

```
_acd () {
  _dirs
  _files -g "*.(7z|rar|tar.bz2|tar.gz|tar.xz|tbz2|tgz|zip)(e\\''REPLY=\${REPLY}\\#'\\')"
}
compdef _acd acd apushd
```

Comment: Personally I would have named it `cdar` so I could pronounce it in a pirate-y voice ("CD arrrrr") or as a homophone for CD-R.